# Use variable from outside (lexical) environment in a macro

Tags: macros, scheme, lisp, common-lisp

How do I get this piece of macro to function as intended? -- I'd like to capture p from the lexical environment without having to send it to the macro as an argument.

```
(define-syntax-rule (fi a b)
    (if p a b)) ;--->capture `p` from lexical env

(let ((p #t))
    (fi 1 2))
```

Bonus thanks -- How would I do the same in CL?

Answer (score 2):

In Common Lisp a macro is simply a function that takes as input the list structure of the code and returns a list structure representing the new code.

```
(defmacro fi (a b)
  `(if p ,a ,b))
```

So if you were to use fi like this:

```
(let ((p t)) ; Common Lisp uses 't' for truth.
   (fi 1 2))
```

It is as if you had typed:

```
(let ((p t))
  (if p 1 2))
```

To see how you would get this expansion, imagine fi was a function and you gave it the arguments of 1 and 2.

```
(fi 1 2) => (if p 1 2)
```

Then took the list structure it returned and substituted it with the call to fi.

The example you give is simple because the arguments evaluate to themselves. If you had something more complicated like the expressions (* 1 1) and (+ 1 1), the actual list structure is passed in (the value of a is the list (* 1 1), and the value of b is the list (+ 1 1))

```
(fi (* 1 1) (+ 1 1)) => (if p (* 1 1) (+ 1 1))
```

Comment: The question isn't about Common Lisp but Scheme.

Comment: @Sylwester From the question "Bonus thanks -- How would I do the same in CL?"

Comment: My bad, Didn't catch that. In that case it would need a tag :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't capture local bindings with `syntax-rules`. You can use `syntax-case` for that, though:

```
(define-syntax fi
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      ((_ a b)
       (with-syntax ((p (datum->syntax stx #'p)))
         #'(if p a b))))))
```

However, using `datum->syntax` to capture identifiers of a fixed name like this is not ideal. If you're using Racket, it's better to use syntax parameters for this.

---

For Scheme implementations that don't have `syntax-case` but have explicit renaming, you might write the macro this way:

```
(define-syntax fi
  (er-macro-transformer
    (lambda (exp rename compare)
      `(,(rename 'if) p ,(cadr exp) ,(caddr exp)))))
```

Some people find it simpler, but the onus is on you to rename *everything* that you're not intentionally capturing. In this case, we're explicitly renaming `if`; for most other macros that use `lambda`, `let`, etc., those all must be renamed.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I'll give this a shot, but out of curiousity, isn't there any way to achieve defmacro like simplicity here?

Comment: @rebnoob Most dialects of Scheme provide define-macro which is almost the same thing.

Comment: As you say, this usage of datum->syntax is problematic.  If you have the same external name bound in the lexical scope of the macro, and also bound locally at the call site (say with a let expression) it will choose the first of them.  define-macro will do the opposite, which is at least a more predictable breakage of hygiene!  I should stick to define-macro, where available, or syntax parameters where available.

Comment: @rebnoob The problem with using a defmacro-like thing in Scheme is that it's too easy to capture other stuff too. For example, in the specific case of this macro, what if `if` is redefined within your current lexical context? (Common Lisp gets around this by having symbol packages, and ensuring that things in the `COMMON-LISP` package can't be redefined. Scheme doesn't have such a concept.) Having said that, if you want the "simplicity", an alternative is to write an explicit-renaming macro. I'll update my post with such an implementation.

Comment: @malisper `define-macro` is easy to define on pretty much any Scheme system that provides something more than `syntax-rules`. However, the trouble with `define-macro` is that it does not have any way to constrain the lack of hygiene. Even gensyms can't cope with the fact that all your "free" identifiers (like `if` in the case of the current macro, or just simple stuff like `lambda` or `let`) can be rebound in the current lexical context.

Comment: @Chris `define-macro` is trivial to define using `syntax-case` (you simply `syntax->datum` the macro body, then `datum->syntax` it back using the current syntax object as the context), so "where available" is redundant. :-) Say goodbye to having sane bindings for all the built-in identifiers your macros use, though!